# How to do parallel GPU inferencing in Tensorflow 2.0 + Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, predict, tensorflow2.0, multi-gpu

Let's begin with the premise that I'm newly approaching to TensorFlow and deep learning in general.

I have TF 2.0 Keras-style model trained using `tf.Model.train()`, two available GPUs and I'm looking to scale down inference times.

I trained the model distributing across GPUs using the extremely handy `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy().scope()` context manager

```
mirrored_strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()

with mirrored_strategy.scope():
  model.compile(...)
  model.train(...)
```

both GPUs get effectively used (even if I'm not quite happy with the results accuracy).

I can't seem to find a similar strategy for distributing inference between GPUs with the `tf.Model.predict()` method: when i run `model.predict()` I get (obviously) usage from only one of the two GPUs.

Is it possible to istantiate the same model on both GPUs and feed them different chunks of data in parallel?

There are posts that suggest how to do it in TF 1.x but I can't seem to replicate the results in TF2.0

https://medium.com/@sbp3624/tensorflow-multi-gpu-for-inferencing-test-time-58e952a2ed95

[Tensorflow: simultaneous prediction on GPU and CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44255362/tensorflow-simultaneous-prediction-on-gpu-and-cpu)

my mental struggles with the question are mainly

- TF 1.x is `tf.Session()`based while sessions are implicit in TF2.0, if I get it correctly, the solutions I read use separate sessions for each GPU and I don't really know how to replicate it in TF2.0
- I don't know how to use the `model.predict()` method with a specific session.

I know that the question is probably not well-formulated but I summarize it as:

Does anybody have a clue on how to run Keras-style `model.predict()` on multiple GPUs (inferencing on a different batch of data on each GPU in a parallel way) in TF2.0?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/save_and_load

This might help. I am having the same issue and it seems like my problem is stemming from the fact that I am saving my model in the hdf5 format which isn't supported when loading the model back into a distributed startegy

Answer (score 1):

Try to load model in `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy` and use greater batch_size

```
mirrored_strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()

with mirrored_strategy.scope():
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(saved_model_path)

result = model.predict(batch_size=greater_batch_size)
```

Comment: This does not work with model.predict_on_batch(greater_batch_size) right?

Answer (score 0):

There still does not seem to be an official example for distributed inference. There is a potential solution here using tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/37686. However, it does not seem to fully utilize multi gpus